# Router for 100Mb Ethernet Circuit

Tags: router, wide-area-network

Can anyone recommend an affordable (for a few hundred £ or less) router for use with a 100Mb ethernet circuit? I think I've scared myself with Cisco prices and searches only seem to yield internet, VPN or UTM devices. I simply want a efficient box to route traffic. Currently I use Allied Telesyn AR410s, but they're long in the tooth and I'm not sure they have sufficient processing power as we're only getting 40Mb through them.

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do shopping recommendations. You should take a peek at the [faq]

Comment: Point of injection? Network size (approx)?

Comment: Thank you to those who replied before my question got closed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using generic hardware with a software solution such as [Pfsense](http://www.pfsense.org/) ?